# C# returning UInt32 vs Int32 - C# thinking 0 and 1 are Int32

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# dll bind to UDK, in which you have to return a unsigned 32 bit integer for bool values - hence 0 is false, anything greater is true. The UDK gets the value and converts it to either true or false...

I was doing some code and found this:

```
[DllExport("CheckCaps", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static UInt32 CheckCaps()
    {
        return ( Console.CapsLock ? 1 : 0);
    }
```

gave me the error of:

> "Error, Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'uint'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

While I understand the error, I didnt have this issue before doing

```
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
```

From the way it looks like C#'s issue with string typecasting, where if you have this:

```
int example = 5;
Console.Writeline( example);
Console.Writeline( example + "");
```

The first console.writeline will give an error because C# won't autotype cast to a string

I understand that there are logical reasons behind these errors (as they occur in these situations) , but is there a fix for this other than doing Convert.ToUInt32(1) and Convert.ToUInt32(0)?

(I'm hoping for a fix akin to how  you can go 0.f for floats, but for unsigned intergers)

Comment: Please learn the difference between an IDE and a compiler. Visual Studio thinks nothing, as it's simply a development environment that hosts several different languages and compilers. The problem is with C#, and *not* Visual Studio. The distinction is important.

Comment: Sorry yes, I do understand that. It was me being lazy... I'll change the question to match

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code below

```
if (File.Exists(filepath))
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

compiles because according to C# standard

> **13.1.7** A constant-expression (§14.16) of type `int` can be converted to type `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the constant-expression is within the range of the destination type.

There is no implicit conversion like that defined for conditional expressions, so your first code snippet needs either an explicit cast or a `U` suffix:

```
return Console.CapsLock ? 1U : 0;
```

Note that only one conversion/suffix is necessary, because zero can be converted to `uint` based on the rule 13.1.7 above.

Answer (score 8):

`1u` is the unsigned literal syntax for 1.  `0u` is for 0.